# can I withdraw funds from a smart contract without a withdraw function?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

Is there a way to withdraw funds from a smart contract that doesn't have a withdrawal function?

I have tried different ways, but I don't understand How can I do it exactly. The contract is deployed with my address, and now I am unable to withdraw funds.

Here is the address of the contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0x2821989877c0189bf63837f18a2856e30297af70#code

Comment: Here is the link of the contract:https://bscscan.com/address/0x2821989877c0189bf63837f18a2856e30297af70#code

Comment: No, it is not possible to withdraw funds from a contract if there is no withdrawal function. The only exception is if the contract implements [SELFDESTRUCT](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/self-destruct/), which could transfer the ETH.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is a fork of `Safemoon` and doesn't include any withdrawal function, so you can't withdraw funds directly.

Since it's not a **proxy** contract, you can't update the contract to include it either.

In simple words, the **funds are locked** in the contract, and you can't access them.